# Online Screen Capture/Recording

Tags: java, javascript

I would like to implement a screen recording function for the users of my website.
This will be for a penny auction style website so that the users can record their bids and provide proof if something goes wrong with the auctions.

Here is a demo of an online recorder. http://www.screentoaster.com/watch/demo/screentoaster

Does anyone know of any framework, script or third party that has these functions?
I would ultimately like to embed a record button into the auction and it would automatically start recording a predefined area.

Comment: I'm confused. Didn't you just link to an online screen recorder? What's wrong with using that one?

Comment: Id like my site to be able to do the things that screentoaster can do so that a user can just click a record button on my site and the video would record in the background until they click stop.

Answer (score 1):

I know this does not directly answer your question, but if I were approaching the issue of proof of purchase I would create a simple server side script for sending a confirmation email/invoice because they can be relied upon in a court of law (ISPs can prove they were sent).

The issue with the screen grabbing approach is that someone could say open developer tools in chrome, edit your webpage to look like he or she has placed a bid before pressing the screen record button.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with: screenr.com